# How can I resolve an Internal Administrator Issue in Atlassian Confluence Server?

Tags: confluence

I'm having an old issue that I would like to fix, once and for all, with Confluence Server.  When I started integrating it with JIRA a while back.  I simply cannot figure out what the hell went wrong with the administrative access to the internal directory.

I often will perform a Health Check, and will always see this:

[image]

So I made sure that I had the access needed, and made sure I assigned myself to the necessary groups:

[image]

I believed, at first, that I made the mistake of adding an Atlassian Crowd directory settings.  However, I'm not running Crowd (which, according to many threads I've read, is accessible from a specific port with '/crowd/'.)  It does synchronize though, for some odd reason, so maybe it's similar to the JIRA directory you can setup (as opposed to Crowd.)  Either way, it doesn't make sense that this would affect access to the internal directory (especially where I have the same user and group setting on JIRA, as well.)

[image]

If I've already attempted a fix that's recommended, then I'll let you know.  Hopefully, I'm overlooking the obvious.  The Users I have setup in Confluence are myself and two colleagues.  The only thing I may have done in the past was delete a user that was automatically given the name of "admin" or something similar.  However, I *am* an admin, so other than the name - I would belong to the same groups (as seen above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error clearly mentioned that you don't have an Administrator User in Confluence Internal Directory. It doesn't mean that you don't have administrator account and it only means that you don't have them in Internal Directory.

That Remote JIRA Directory, means you are using JIRA as an external user directory. In Atlassian Applications JIRA and Crowd are both using embedded Crowd Directory for authentication with Confluence. Thus, that shouldn't be a big deal. The point here is you do have an external user directory on higher position.

Technically, position of the user directories are really important for Confluence. Because during user creation and authentication, Confluence checks the first directory. If the user exists will use the first directory for login.

With what you mentioned, I would say, your user name is in JIRA and it's getting synchronised with Confluence via that user directory. That's why you do have same users in both JIRA and Confluence.

Why you are seeing that error and why it's concern for health check is, if you encounter to a network issue with JIRA Server or JIRA Server won't be accessible, you need to have on internal user for troubleshooting propose.

For fixing this issue you do have two options:

**1. First Solution:**

Change the Confluence Internal Directory into the **first position**. Create a user admin and assign it to Confluence User and Confluence Administrator Group. Change the position of your Remote JIRA Directory back to first place.

**2. Create user from database**

You can use the options from [this document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/restore-passwords-to-recover-admin-user-rights-158390.html) and create an admin user in your Internal Directory.

**Tips:**

1. When you creating user, please make sure that it won't have same name as other administrator users in JRIA Directory.
2. Create backup from your database prior to change anything. That way, you can ensure that you won't locked out from application.

Comment: Although I don't like the idea of unwanted user accounts, the first solution worked the best since I'm pretty sure I removed the original admin account (figuring that I already had one via JIRA.)  The comment about not being locked out if there needs to be some type of troubleshooting was also a valuable tip that I was obviously overlooking.

Reviewing the user accounts, all the others were set to the Remote JIRA Directory, and when I did as you recommended, I realized that I finally had one set to the Confluence Internal Directory again. Thanks!